# Reuse catch for all catches

Tags: c#, try-catch

is it possible to do something like the following:

I want to catch a custom exception and do something with it - easy: `try {...} catch (CustomException) {...}`

But then i want to run the code used in the "catch all" block still run some other code which is relevant to all catch blocks...

```
try
{
    throw new CustomException("An exception.");
}
catch (CustomException ex)
{
    // this runs for my custom exception

throw;
}
catch
{
    // This runs for all exceptions - including those caught by the CustomException catch
}
```

or do i have to put whatever i want to do in all exception cases (`finally` is not an option because i want it only to run for the exceptions) into a separate method/nest the whole try/catch in another (*euch*)...?

Comment: Setting a flag in the catch statements and using a 'finally' would work for you.  Alternatively factor out all the common code into a `CleanUpAfterException` method and call it at the end of each `catch` statement.

Comment: Ah - setting a flag and 'finally' seems like a sort of neat solution. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally do something along the lines of

```
try
{ 
    throw new CustomException("An exception.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   if (ex is CustomException)
   {
        // Do whatever
   }
   // Do whatever else
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the neatest... at least the try block isn't indented also. As it happens i have only one method call to do in both cases, so a separate method wouldn't gain anything.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use two `try` blocks:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a custom exception");
        throw;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is for all exceptions, "+
        "including those caught and re-thrown above");
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, seems a bit messy though - lots of nesting!

Answer (score 2):

Just do the overall catch and check to see if the exception is that type:

```
try
{
   throw new CustomException("An exception.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   if (ex is CustomException)
   {
       // Custom handling
   }
   // Overall handling
}
```

Alternately, have a method for overall exception handling that both call:

```
try
{
   throw new CustomException("An exception.");
}
catch (CustomException ex)
{
    // Custom handling here

    HandleGeneralException(ex);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   HandleGeneralException(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't do this way, you either catch a specific exception (linearly) or a generalisation. If you wish to run something for *all* exceptions you would need to keep a record of whether or not an exception has been thrown, perhaps what it was etc, and use `finally`, or another contrived, probably more 'messy' and verbose, mechanism.